# Abstract Algebra (Ring Homomorphisms and Ideals)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that the equation $y^2=4$ has at least $4$ solutions in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. What do you conclude?

My main question about this is what $\mathbb{Z}/5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ really means. I know this question is asking  to show there are at least $4$ polynomials $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5[x]$ such that $f(x)^2=4$ (mod x^2+1), but I don't know how to solve this. I feel like I would divide $\sqrt{4}=2$ by $x^2+1$ but I can't do this in the integers, only the rationals. Can someone please help me? Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Since you are taking the quotient by the ideal generated by $x^2+1$ all the polynomials in $R$ will have degree at most $1$.  Even before we take the quotient $2$ and $3$ are both such that $2^2=3^2=4$.  The quotient tells us that, in $R$, $x^2=-1=4$.  So, $x$ is a solution.  You need only find one more.

Comment: Oh ok, so the last solution would be x+1 because (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1=4. Is this correct?

Comment: @Dillon No.  What you have reduces to $x^2+2x+1=2x$, because $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: Oh I see. I don't want you to give me the answer straight up, but can you show me how I would find the last solution. Is it just trial and error or what?

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. Are the 4 solutions ±2x+(x^2+1) and ±1+(x^2+1)?

Comment: @Dillon I gave $3$ solutions in my answer.  For the fourth, search for a polynomial such that $(p(x))^2=4$ where you are allowed to make $x^2+1=0$.